# Как инициализировать bxslider во вплывающем окне?

Tags: jquery, всплывающее-окно, fancybox

Здравствуйте. Вопрос в следующем.

По клику на ссылку вызываю всплывающее окно (fancybox), внутрь которого загружаю другим скриптом (bxslider) галерею фото. Окно показываю так:

```
$('.gallery-link').fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            locked : false

        }
    },
    afterLoad: function(){
        showGallery();
    },
    afterClose: function(){
        destroyGallery();
    }
});
```

`showGallery` - это функция, которой я, используя bxslider, формирую нужную мне галерею, код ниже:

```
 function showGallery(){

if ($('.gallery-thumbs-list').length > 0) {

    var thumb = $('.gallery-thumbs-list').find('.thumb');

    var visibleThumbs = 6;

    //Слайдер больших фото
    gallerySlider = $('.gallery-images').bxSlider({
        controls: true,
        pager: false,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuint',
        infiniteLoop: true,
        speed: 500,
        mode: 'fade',
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 1,
        slideWidth: 700,
        onAfterSlide: function (currentSlideNumber) {
            thumb.removeClass('pager-active');
            thumb.eq(currentSlideNumber).addClass('pager-active');
        },
        onNextSlide: function (currentSlideNumber) {
            slideThumbs(currentSlideNumber, visibleThumbs);
        },
        onPrevSlide: function (currentSlideNumber) {
            slideThumbs(currentSlideNumber, visibleThumbs);
        }
    });

    thumb.click(function (e) {

        gallerySlider.goToSlide($(this).closest('.thumb-item').index() - 6);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function slideThumbs(currentSlideNumber, visibleThumbs) {

        var m = Math.floor(currentSlideNumber / visibleThumbs);
        var slideTo = m * visibleThumbs;

        thumbsSlider.goToSlide(slideTo);
    }

    $('.gallery-thumbs-list').find('.thumb').click(function () {

        $('.gallery-thumbs-list').find('.thumb').removeClass('pager-active');
        $(this).addClass('pager-active');

    });

    //Слайдер миниатюр для навигации
    thumbsSlider = $('.gallery-thumbs-list').bxSlider({
        controls: false,
        pager: false,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuint',
        displaySlideQty: visibleThumbs,
        moveSlideQty: visibleThumbs,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 8,
        slideWidth: 73,
        slideMargin: 20
    });
    }
}
```

Все ок, за исключением одного: всплывающее окно появляется пустым. Контролы слайдера на месте, но фоток нет. Но если в этот момент попробовать ресайзить окно браузера, то - вуаля! - фотки загружаются, все работает как нужно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил. 
Добавил в обработчик `afterShow()` `fancybox` вызов `gallerySlider.reloadSlider();`

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте воспользоваться функцией reloadSlider после прогрузки окна.
afterShow: function(){
     gallerySlider.reloadSlider({
    ...
     );
}

Comment: Спасибо. Уже сам додумался. См. комментарий под вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

Предыдущий комментарий верен. Я лишь немного дополню. В момент инициализации слайдера контейнер и элементы слайдера должны быть видимыми, чтобы скрипт мог вычислить размеры. При расположении слайдера в окне Fancybox видимым он становится в тот момент, когда Fancybox показывает нам окно, поэтому после показа окна (по коллбэку afterShow) нам нужно либо запустить инициализацию слайдера:

```
gallerySlider = $('.gallery-images').bxSlider({
    controls: true,
    pager: false,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuint',
    infiniteLoop: true,
    speed: 500,
    mode: 'fade',
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 1,
    slideWidth: 700,
    onAfterSlide: function (currentSlideNumber) {
        thumb.removeClass('pager-active');
        thumb.eq(currentSlideNumber).addClass('pager-active');
    },
    onNextSlide: function (currentSlideNumber) {
        slideThumbs(currentSlideNumber, visibleThumbs);
    },
    onPrevSlide: function (currentSlideNumber) {
        slideThumbs(currentSlideNumber, visibleThumbs);
    }
});
```

либо перегрузить его, если он был инициализирован ранее:

```
gallerySlider.reloadSlider();
```